# Passing an Object between Forms in C#

Tags: c#, object, parameter-passing

I've created an Object Array of Students and I want to pass in from one form to another. When I try to do so I get"

```
Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'College_Life.Student[]' is less accessible than method 'College_Life.frmStudentOutput.frmStudentOutput(College_Life.Student[])
```

**The 1st FORM looks like this :**

```
namespace College_Life
{
    public partial class frmInput : Form
    {
        private int intCount;
        private Student[] ALevel = new Student[1];
.
.
.
        private void cmdSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //
            frmStudentOutput OutputForm = new frmStudentOutput(ALevel);
            OutputForm.Show();
        }
```

.
.
.
**The 2nd Form looks like**

```
    private Student[] ALStudent;

    public frmStudentOutput(Student[] ALStudent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
```

Hope you can help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open the Student class and check if it is public.

It should look like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
         //...
    }
    //...
}
```